# webdriver-manager is not recognized as an internal or external command, although I installed protractor globally (Jenkins)

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor

I'm trying to install [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) globally and download Selenium binaries by executing following commands.

```
npm install -g protractor
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager update --ie
```

When I execute them directly from CMD or Powershell console, they works properly.
Unfortunately, when I try to execute them from Jenkins (on exactly the same machine), only the first command is executed properly. Next one gives an error:

> 'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

It doesn't matter whether I execute those command from 'execute windows batch command' step nor 'Windows Powershell'

[image]

Does it mean that `path` variable is not updated when installing Protractor?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the npm global package install folder to the `PATH` environment. Considering you run script by Jenkins, it's not recommend modify the `PATH` environment on Jenkins slave machine.

**1)** The better way is to use local `protractor` and `webdriver-manager` of your project.

You should add `protractor` into your project's `package.json` as a dependency. Then execute `npm install` by `Window Batch Command` to install all dependencies.

After that, you can get `protractor` and `webdriver-manager` from `<project folder>/node_modules/.bin/protractor` and `<project folder>/node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager` respectively.

So your `Window Batch Command` should be like:

```
npm install
./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --proxy <your proxy>
./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --ie --proxy <your proxy>
```

Make sure the `npm install` executed under folder where the `package.json` inside.
If you don't know how to do that, update your project folder structure in screenshot in your question.

**2)** If you prefer to modify the `PATH` environment dynamically, your Window Batch Command should be like:

```
npm config get prefix > prefix
set /P prefix=<prefix
set PATH=%prefix%;%PATH%

npm install -g protractor
webdriver-manager version
webdriver-manager update --proxy <your proxy>
webdriver-manager update --ie  --proxy <your proxy>
```

Comment: I already use local Protractor in my project...*but* since network proxy on Jenkins machine is blocking access to the files that `webdriver-update` is trying to download, when reporting a request to unlock it on proxy, I would like to show the simplest commands possible to proxy administrator. I do not want to confuse him/her by refering to local webdriver. I want to show him: look there's extremely simple Jenkins job and it fails, because of proxy (it also fails from CMD console).

Comment: I updated answer to modify `PATH` dynamically.  For proxy issue, you can append `--proxy <your company proxy>` to `webdriver-manager` command.

Comment: I don't know why, but I don't see the output from `webdriver-manager update` in Jenkins console (using your solution).
Thus I wrote a Powershell script that (finally) gives me an output

```
$npmPath = iex "npm config get prefix"

pushd $npmPath

./webdriver-manager update
./webdriver-manager update --ie

popd
```

Comment: Did you still meet the error `'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as an internal or external command`  when you use my solution in option 2?

Comment: No, but I don't see any output (should be tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403), thus I don't know whether command is really executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173634/discussion-between-matandked-and-yong).