# Gitlab CI End to End testing failing because of webdriver-manager is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, selenium, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am working on a nodejs project that has some End to End tests. The test are running fine on my local and it failing from my gitlab pipeline because of webdriver was not recognized.

I tried installing webdriver in couple of different ways like Protractor but not fixed my issues. Any help would be appriciated.

**Here is my gitlab-ci.yml file**

stages:

- build
- test

before_script:

- npm install # install npm packages
- npm install protractor -g

build:

stage: build

script:

```
- npm run build
```

test:

stage: test

script:

```
- npm run test:e2e
```

only:

```
- master
```

**Error from pipeline**

webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl --gecko false
'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@0.1.0 pree2e: `webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl --gecko false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that can help you
https://github.com/serenity-js/serenity-js/issues/276
and [webdriver-manager is not recognized as an internal or external command, although I installed protractor globally (Jenkins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963120/webdriver-manager-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-although)

Comment: Thankyou. By add it to my package.json fixed the issue.

Comment: If it help you, you should accept answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers